# How to use the DBTable macro in slick

Tags: slick

I can't find any documentation for the use of DBTable type macros.
I just want to do something like this:

```
object Coffees extends DBTable("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/coffeeShop","COFFEES")
```

but i can't get it run....

Can anyone help me with an example.

THX

nilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't exist yet. There is a prototype on github. https://github.com/xeno-by/typemacros-h2db Further work on this topic recently started.